# The fetch type first cannot be used with forward only cursors

Tags: sql-server

how to solve this question, there no any useful info for this
I met in sql-server, when I try to reuse the cursor

Comment: Best possible solution....stop using a cursor. Seriously, what are you actually trying to do? Cursors are horrible for performance and should be only for a very few administrative tasks. Show us your code and we can help you find a set based solution instead of RBAR (row by agonizing row).

Comment: It’s a forward only cursor and you are trying to go backwards and confused why that is an error?

Comment: Upvoted as it is perfectly valid question stemming from the fact that FORWARD_ONLY is hidden default on cursors, the point is that it is not clear intuitively. No need to explain "what are you actually trying to do", it is irrelevant, there are use cases for cursors (otherwise they would became obsolete and discouraged).

Answer (score 4):

see: [DECLARE CURSOR (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql)

> ```
> DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR [ LOCAL | GLOBAL ]   
>      [ FORWARD_ONLY | SCROLL ]
> ```

...

> FORWARD_ONLY Specifies that the cursor can only be scrolled from the
>   first to the last row. FETCH NEXT is the only supported fetch option.

Think of a car with no reverse gear = FORWARD_ONLY (and hence you cannot go backwards)

You need to specify SCROLL instead when declaring the cursor. However almost invariably it is faster to use SQL (no cursor) instead.

Comment: Upvoted, `SCROLL` syntaxe was the little piece I was looking for. Just the last sentence - I wonder, how do you replace `CURSOR` with SQL, where you have dependant iterations?

Comment: There is no single answer to your question. "It depends" on what you need to do. Choose SQL if you can.

Comment: Well, here's a example of a task with dependant iterations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56949082/using-cte-recursion-for-stacking-splittable-items-into-bins]. I don't know of a way of avoiding CURSORS for such tasks, that is why I'm asking...

Comment: Upvoted with a note that the "Think of a car with no reverse gear" metaphore is not helpful as FORWARD_ONLY is self-explanatory and more clear than the metaphore itself. What is not clear that the FORWARD_ONLY is the hidden default, I took a liberty to post an answer as an extended comment to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Paul Maxwell's answer is correct, just adding an authoritative [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46553198/the-fetch-type-first-cannot-be-used-with-forward-only-cursors), look into **Remarks** section:

> If the SCROLL option is not specified in an ISO style DECLARE CURSOR statement, NEXT is the only FETCH option supported. If SCROLL is specified in an ISO style DECLARE CURSOR, all FETCH options are supported.

This means that FORWARD_ONLY is hidden default and only if the cursor is declared

```
DECLARE cursor_name CURSOR SCROLL ...
```

then `FETCH FIRST` is available.